# Can not start keystone service

Tags: linux, puppet, fedora, openstack, keystone

I installed packstack on my fresh installation of Fedora 21 with all updates. When I run

`packstack --allinone` I received this error:

```
ERROR : Error appeared during Puppet run: 192.168. 1.*_keystone.pp Error:
Could not start Service[keystone]: Execution of '/sbin/service openstack-keystone
start'` returned 1: Redirecting to /bin/systemctl start  openstack-keystone.service 
You will find full trace in log /var/tmp/packstack/20141223-022613-whLvTs/manifests 
/192.168.1.*_keystone.pp.log
```

And this is the log:

```
Notice: /Stage[main]/Cinder::Keystone::Auth/Keystone_user_role[cinder@services]:
Dependency Service[keystone] has failures: true
Warning: /Stage[main]/Cinder::Keystone::Auth/Keystone_user_role[cinder@services]:
Skipping because of failed dependencies
Notice: Finished catalog run in 13.02 seconds
```

With systemctl status openstack-keystone.service get this:

```
openstack-keystone.service - OpenStack Identity Service (code-named Keystone)
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/openstack-keystone.service; disabled)
Active: failed (Result: start-limit) since Tue 2014-12-23 19:47:36 EET; 1min 59s ago
Process: 22526 ExecStart=/usr/bin/keystone-all (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Main PID: 22526 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

    Dec 23 19:47:35 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start OpenStack...
    Dec 23 19:47:35 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit openstack-keystone.s...
    Dec 23 19:47:35 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: openstack-keystone.servic...
    Dec 23 19:47:36 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: start request repeated to...
    Dec 23 19:47:36 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start OpenStack...
    Dec 23 19:47:36 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit openstack-keystone.s...
    Dec 23 19:47:36 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: openstack-keystone.servic...
```

Answer (score -1):

This can happen due SELinux avc denial because of a missing policy.
You can try to put SELinux to permissive mode:

```
# setenforce 0
```

[A similar bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1174795)